# Using pysqldf with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was using the pandasql package to do some data manipulations with Pandas. My dataframe is enormous so I've been looking into ways to speed up my computations. One blog (found [here](https://statcompute.wordpress.com/tag/pandasql/)) claims that the pysqldf package is much faster. However, I can't get it to work with a Pandas dataframe.

Specifically, here's what I have:

```
from pysqldf import SQLDF
sqldf = SQLDF(globals()) #also tried with locals(), doesn't make a difference
#I know the sql is good, I've used it elsewhere (in R)
result = sqldf.execute("Select * from data where blah")
```

Here, `data` is a Pandas dataframe that I know exists, but I keep getting the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: data
```

It appears from my web search, including the link above, that the usual operation of this package is with a sqlite db that has been stored in memory. However, the documentation (found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqldf)) makes it seem like it can be used directly on a dataframe, like pandasql or R's sqldf.

The question: If the pysqldf package can really be used like this, how can I make it recognize my dataframe?

Comment: Bump, I would also like to get this to work. Even their sample code gives this error. 

I'd be happy to use pandasql, but I need to define some functions which are in my queries, which pandasql doesn't allow.

Why have these packages not been updated in like 5 years?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with pysqldf. Maybe you should try pandasql. I saw the documentation and seems really similar with pysqldf (https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/ , https://pypi.org/project/pysqldf/).  Try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import *

meat = load_meat() 
df = sqldf("SELECT * FROM meat LIMIT 5; ",globals())
print(df)
```

Comment: pandasql seems to work fine, but doesn't allow user defined functions. Any ideas on getting pysqldf to work would be very useful thanks.